# ¿Como Ajustar mapa al cambiar de tamaño el div?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, ionic

El `<div>` donde genero el mapa al cambiar el tamaño la posicion central del mapa, se invierte. Cuando el `<div>` contiene la clase `"mapCambia"` el `center` del mapa se mantiene en la posicion anterior, y cuando este regresa a su posicion inicial, direcciona el `center` al centro de la dimension que tiene la clase `mapCambia`

la etiqueta con id `"MyMap"` es la que contiene el mapa, la etiqueta con la clase `"absolute"`es el boton que me redimensiona los `<div>`

```
 <div id="MyMap" class="map"></div>
 <div class="absolute button button-outline:color ion-navicon button-dark"></div>
 <div class="lista">
        <ion-list scroll="true">
            <ion-radio ng-repeat="lugares in array_marcadores">{{lugares.posicion}}</ion-radio>
        </ion-list>
    </div>
```

archivo.js

```
 eldiv = document.getElementById('MyMap'),  cerca = 4,
 points = [
            {
                lat: 15.774703,
                lng: -75.83020
            },
            {
                lat: -15.8654,
                lng: 145.465
            }
    ],
        sel_point = 0,

 mapOptions = {
            center: points[sel_point],
            scrollwheel: true,
            zoom: cerca,
            zoomControl: true,
            disableDefaultUI: true,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        },

  function initialize() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(eldiv, mapOptions);
    }

  document.getElementsByClassName('absolute')[0].onclick = function () {
        if (!lalista.classList.contains('mapCambia')) {
            boxOne.classList.toggle('mapCambia');
            btnone.classList.toggle('botonlista');
            lalista.classList.toggle('listaCambia');
        }
        dimensionar(map);
    };
    function dimensionar(m) {
            x = m.getZoom();
            c = m.getCenter();
            google.maps.event.trigger(m, 'resize');
            m.setZoom(x);
            m.setCenter(c);
    };

 google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Style.css

```
.absolute.botonlista {
position: relative;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
width: 40px;
}
.absolute {
position: relative;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
width: 40px;
z-index: 99;
bottom: 25px;
transition: 2s;
}
.lista {
height: 0%;
width: 100%;
z-index: 98;
transition: 2s;
}
.lista.listaCambia {
height: 65%;
width: 100%;
z-index: 98;
}
```

Comment: Podrias mostrar la función que redimensiona el div?

Comment: ya añadi, el estilo y la funcion que redimensiona

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La única duda que me cabe es si `archivo.js` tiene más contenido antes de declarar `eldiv` porque eso debiera tirar un error si no está antecedido por `var`.

Suponiendo que antes de eldiv tienes declarada la variable `map` de la forma

```
var map,
    eldiv = document.getElementById('MyMap'),  
    cerca = 4,
    points=[...]
```

Entonces otras funciones tienen acceso a la variable `map` en el contexto global. Si ese es el caso, entonces sólo te falta gatillar el evento `resize` cuando redimensiones el div:

```
function initialize() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(eldiv, mapOptions);
}

document.getElementsByClassName('absolute')[0].onclick = function () {
    if (!lalista.classList.contains('mapCambia')) {
        boxOne.classList.toggle('mapCambia');
        btnone.classList.toggle('botonlista');
        lalista.classList.toggle('listaCambia');
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
    }
};
```

Este evento puede cambiar el centro del mapa, por lo que tal vez quieras guardar una referencia al centro antes de redimensionar, y centrar el mapa después de redimensionar. Probablemente no sea el caso.

Además, aquí hay una racing condition, porque puede que el mapa se redimensione antes de que el div cambie de posición. En ese caso podrías agregar un breve timeout al trigger de resize.

**Edit:** añadiendo el timeout, la expresión de función onlick quedaría:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('absolute')[0].onclick = function () {
    if (!lalista.classList.contains('mapCambia')) {
        boxOne.classList.toggle('mapCambia');
        btnone.classList.toggle('botonlista');
        lalista.classList.toggle('listaCambia');
        window.setTimeout(function() {
          google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
        },500);
    }
};
```

Donde 500 es un valor tentativo. Dependiendo de la definición de estilos, el redimensionamiento del div podría tomar más que 500ms.

Comment: si me redimensiona solo que lo hace invertido, cuando el div cambia su tamaño a mas pequeño, el centro del mapa se mantiene, cuando vuelvo a dar click en el boton, ahora si realiza el cambio

Comment: Por eso, agrega un window.setTimeout antes de gatillar el evento resize sobre el mapa. Mira el edit de mi respuesta.

Comment: aun no me funciona

Comment: Lo lamento. En todo caso, ¿Qué es lo que determina si lalista tiene clase mapCambia? Eso está en duro?

Comment: para poder hacer el ajuste de boxOne, lalista no contiene la clase mapCambia, por lo cual el boton con clase absolute, puede hacer su funcion de cambiar de tamaño